# How to make a RV730/M96-XT [Mobility Radeon HD 4670] GPU, works in Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, 21.04

Just installed Ubuntu 21.04 in a Late 2009 iMac.
At first boot screen is divided in four. Then added `nomodeset` to `/etc/default/grub` and Ubuntu is able to boot, but Graphics are rendered by `llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 128 bits)`, shown in settings.
It seems this is a common issue for some Radeon GPU, I have look in several forums but had not find an answer.
Would be nice to find somebody who actually has this problem solved!!